# How do I rotate a drill (or any other item that can be rotated)?

Tags: core-keeper

I just built a drill in Core Keeper and I can't figure out how to rotate it so that it will point at a deposit. It always seems to point north. How can I rotate the drill, either while placing it, or after placing it?

I don't see anything listed in the controls / settings. I see posts about having 8 drills on one resource node though, which implies there are 2 on each side all facing inward, so I believe it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this guide](https://techraptor.net/gaming/guides/core-keeper-drill-guide):

> Rotate the Drill by pressing E so that the drill bit faces the ore rock.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, it's the Interact key (E by default), after the drill is placed, and you really have to be at the right spot. Highlighting it is not enough.